Unable to start Ubuntu server after installing LDAP client
I'm having a problem with an installation.
The setup consists of a server with OPENLDAP and OPENVPN server configured.
I configured a client that connects to the server via the VPN, I followed the steps for configuring the client and I was able to authenticate correctly.
The problem, however, is that upon restart, when the VPN has not yet started and the server is not yet reachable, the client goes into a loop during the restart. In fact, some services such as Network Manager and others fail to start.
Screenshot fail to start
I've seen other threads like 17.10 ldap - client cannot connect to server and stays in boot loop but I've tried editing ldap.conf with soft policy or setting connection retries/timeout but nothing seems to change.
Any suggestion about?
BR
